# PHP AJAX UPLOAD?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am having problem uplaoding file,
here are my codes:
Any help? Thanks!

test.html

```
function insertPhoto()
{
    var description = document.getElementById('description').value;
    var image = document.getElementById('photo').value;
        var url = "ajax_insert.php?action=add&image="+image+"&description="+description;
    var ajaxRequest = ajax_obj();

            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

                document.getElementById("msgbox").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;

            }             
        }

        ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, true);
            ajaxRequest.send(null);

        return false;
}

<div align="center">
  <div class="top" >
    <div>
       Decription <input name="description" type="text" id="description" value="" maxlength="20" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:5px" >
 Image
        <input name="photo" type="file" id="photo" value="" maxlength="20" />
    </div>
    <div class="buttondiv">
        <input name="button" type="button" value="Upload" onclick="return insertPhoto()" style="margin-left:-10px; height:23px"  /> 
        <span id="msgbox" style="display:none"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ajax_insert.php

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('priceless');
    define('DIR_IMAGE','images/');

    $image = $_GET['image'];
    $description = $_GET['description'];
    $dbtable = 'photos';
    $action = $_GET['action'];

    if($action == 'add'){
           $photo = '';
                if ($_FILES[$image]['name']) {
                    $aray = explode(".",$_FILES[$image]['name']);
                    $ext = $aray[count($aray)-1];
                    $photo = date('Ymdhis').'.'.$ext;
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image]['tmp_name'],DIR_IMAGE.$photo);
                } 

               $data = array(
              'image'=> $photo,
              'description'=> $description
               );
                $values = array();
                foreach($data as $show){
                    $values[] = $show;
                }        
              $query = "INSERT INTO ".$dbtable." (`".implode("`,`",array_keys($data))."`) values ('".implode("','",array_values($values))."')";
              if ($result= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())) {        
                 echo "You have Sucessfully Upload Photo!";              
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Could you please fix your question for the codes to become legible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use this Ajax upload http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ and I'm satisfied with results.

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload files using pure AJAX, because you can't access the file's contents programmatically due to security issues.

You can use an iframe and specify it as the target of the upload form.

You can see an example of it here: http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload files using pure AJAX, because you can't access the file's contents programmatically.

You would have to use a different technique, e.g. submitting the form the normal way into a hidden `iframe` element. That's the way the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) does it.

Comment: With HTML 5 you can convert an image into a data URL and then post that via AJAX.

Comment: @Steve-o yes, but not any arbitrary file from the hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some AJAXy upload, look at Uploadify - http://www.uploadify.com/

It can handle multiple uploads at once, and has a real time progress bar. It then has JS parameters to allow you to handle the upload etc.

If you need a full tutorial give me a shout and I will show you some examples!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because of security issues, many browsers do not let you pass data from a file select field through javascript/ajax.  It is better to use a page that calls itself, with a  normal submit button.  (I've tried AJAX uploads on my own website, so believe me).

Try -

```
<?php
if ($_FILE['file'] != ''){
 $dest = 'folder/';
    list($name, $ext) = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);

    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
    @move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $dest.$name.'.'.$ext);
    };
};
?>
```